# Introduction to linear regression

Tags: regression, references

As part of my work (programmer), I need to learn some linear regression. I have a degree in pure mathematics, but not in statistics. Could anyone be able to give me a good book, an introduction, in linear regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At this point we have 19 questions focused on resources for learning regression: please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=book%20regression%20-logistic%20wiki%3ayes%20is%3aquestion%20duplicate%3ano).

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression is one of the core topics in statistics and hence should get some coverage in any introductory statistics textbook.

Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models* is a well-respected textbook on regression that includes an early chapter with an overview of more basic statistical concepts. That chapter may not be enough if you have no background in statistics at all, though.